# Obtener entidades hijas desde la tabla principal

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Buenas estoy haciendo una prueba, y tengo dos tablas Productos y Marcas. La relación entre ellas es de 1:M es decir una marca puedes estar presente o puede abarcar varios productos, mientras que un producto solo pertenece a una marca. Este es el código que enlazo con la tabla productos.

```
var lista = db.Marcas.Include("Productos.Imagenes").ToList();
```

Pero de esta lista que me devolverá todos las marcas, quiero obtener los productos que están dentro. Entonces pensé que de esta manera me los iba a devolver, pero al parecer no devuelve nada.

```
var pr = lista.Select(ma => ma.Productos.ToList());
```

Si alguien me puede explicar como obtener entidades hijas desde una clase padre. Y si hay una mejor manera de hacerlo. Si es posible quisiera realizar filtros, y solo obtener un determinado producto, intuyo que puede ser con (Where), lo he intentado pero realmente no logro nada. Gracias.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta, pero si tienes una lista de marcas y cada marca tiene varios productos. Basta con tomar una marca `var marcaElegida = db.Marcas.Where(x => x.Id == 1).First()` y luego con `marcaElegida.Productos` tienes una lista de todos los productos que pertenecen a esa marca. Ahora bien, para que esto funcione en tu clase Marcas deberías tener un `public virtual List<Productos> Productos {get; set;}` para que haya una relación de 1 a muchos.

Comment: @JesusPocoata yo tampoco interpreto la pregunta, pero si no me equivoco, el `public virtual` sería necesario en caso de no usar el `.Include("Productos.Imagenes")` en el caso de usarlo es el mismo resultado, basta con que declare `public List<Productos> `

Comment: @Juan Totalmente de acuerdo. Hay varias formas. Bueno creo que es la costumbre, yo uso el virtual para las relaciones entre entidades...

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que deseas basta con agregar a la clase Marca lo siguiente:

```
    public class Marca
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        //esta es la relación de la que te hablaba Jesus Pocoata
        public virtual ICollection<Producto> Productos { get; set; } 
    }
```

y a tu clase Producto agrégale también

```
public virtual Marca Marca { get; set; }
```

y en la vista Index de Marcas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Marca>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </th>
        <th>Productos</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
            </td>
            <td>
                //Aqui recorres todos los productos por cada Marca
                @foreach (var p in item.Productos.ToList())
                {
                    <p>@p.Nombre</p><br/>
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

No te recomiendo que hagas esto, ya que dependiendo de la cantidad de datos seguramente vas a caer en un problema de rendimiento.

El mejor enfoque posible que puedes hacer es crear al menos servicio con dos metodos:

```
public class ServicioProductos
{
     public IList<Producto> ObtenerProductos()
     {}

     public IList<Imagen> ObtenerImagenesDeProductos(int[] productos)
     {}
}
```

Estos servicios te retornaran los productos y las imagenes de los productos que le envíes.

Despues de esto, en el Controlador puedes llamar los dos metodos y cruzar por medio de un modelo los datos. Algo así:

Modelo

```
  public class ListadoProductosModel
{
    public IList<Producto> Productos{get;set;}
    ... demás propiedades
}

public class ProductoModel
{

  public IList<Imagen> Imagenes {get; set;}
   .... demás propiedades
}
```

Controlador

```
public class ProductosController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Get()
  {
    var productos = servicio.ObtenerProductos();
    var imagenes = servicio.ObtenerImagenes(productos.Select(c => c.Id).ToArray());

    var model = new ListadoProductosModel();
    model.Productos = productos; // hacer conversion

    foreach(var p in model.Productos)
       p.Imagenes = imagenes.Where(c=> c.ProductId == p.Id);

    return this.View(model);
  }
}
```

Toca hacer más código, pero definitvamente va a ser mucho más eficiente tu consulta.